# Plant identification in UK

Tags: species-identification

I need some help identifying this plant please. It is summer flowering in the UK. Its height is approximately 30cm, flowers approximately 2cm across.[image]

Comment: I'm drawing a blank. Any chance of showing us the leaves? Is it a wild flower? Could it be a garden escape?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no better images which show the leaves Alan, however I think I may have managed to identify it after much searching. I do believe it is a variety of Viscaria oculata. I sincerely appreciate you going to the trouble of responding and trying to help though, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plant has been identified as Viscaria oculata.